# Continuous dependence on the RHS in ODEs, and related exercises

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

In Birkhoff and Rota's "Ordinary Differential Equations", p. 177, the following theorem is formulated (I've modified it slightly):

> Let $\mathbf{x}(t)$ and $\mathbf{y}(t)$ satisfy the DEs
>   $$\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}/ \mathrm{d}t= \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x},t) \quad \text{ and } \quad \mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}/\mathrm{d} t= \mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{y},t) $$
>   respectively, on $a \leq t \leq b$. Further, let the functions $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ be defined and continuous in a common domain $D \times [a,b]$, and let
>   $$|\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{z},t)-\mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{z},t)|\leq \epsilon, \quad a\leq t \leq b, \quad \mathbf{z} \in D $$
>   Finally let $\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x},t)$ satisfy the Lipschitz condition
>   $$|\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x},t)-\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{y},t)| \leq L |\mathbf x-\mathbf y|, \quad \text{if} \quad (\mathbf{x},t),(\mathbf{y},t) \in D \times [a,b]. $$
>   Then
>   $$|\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{y}(t)| \leq |\mathbf{x}(a)-\mathbf{y}(a)| \mathrm{e}^{L|t-a|}+ \frac{\epsilon}{L} \left[ \mathrm{e}^{L|t-a|}-1 \right].$$
>   The function $\mathbf{Y}$ is not required to satisfy a Lipschitz condition.

The proof of the above then makes use of a differential inequality, with the "equals case" being a Bernoulli differential equation. I'm upset at the fact that the authors haven't mentioned on what $t$-interval the result of the theorem holds. I suspect that the interval could be shorter than $[a,b]$, if the solutions leave the domain $D$.

---

Later, in the exercises they ask to "bound the difference on $[0,1]$ between solutions having the same initial value $y(0)=c$ for the DEs
$$y'=\mathrm{e}^y \; \text{and} \; y'=1+y+\cdots+\frac{y^n}{n!}. "$$
When trying to solve this exercise, I've identified the first RHS, $\mathrm{e}^y$ with $\mathbf{X}$. The first equation can be solved explicitly as
$$y(x)=-\log(\mathrm{e}^{-c}-x), $$
with the interval of existence being $$(-\infty, \mathrm{e}^{-c}). $$
Hence, the exercise doesn't even make sense for $c \geq 0$. Even if I assume that $c<0$, I'm having difficulties finding a domain $D \ni y$, such that the solution will remain in it for $x \in [0,1]$ (which should be done without solving the equation, I suppose).

---

Overall my questions are:

- In the statement of the theorem, what is the interval on which the conclusion holds? Can a claim of its size be made at all?
- How can one solve the aforementioned exercise?

Thank you!